# Target x64 or x86 registers automatically

Tags: assembly

Instead of writing

```
ifndef X64
  mov eax, dest
else
  mov rax, dest
endif
```

is there a way to write that in one line of code that will automatically use the correct register depending on the machine target?

Answer (score 1):

What assembler and environment are you using? Maybe you can define a macro which expands to eax and rax depending on the target.

AFAIK, the default mode for most x86-64 toolchain is that the executable is always placed in low 4GB of the address space. (Shared libraries can be placed in higher addresses, though.) This assumptions is almost always true, and helps reduce code size. Also, writing to `eax` implicitly clears high 32 bits of `rax`. So you can (probably) safely write `eax` in both 32- and 64-bit...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could write a bunch of macros to do it, but I'm not sure how effective it would be as not all operations are compatible across 64 and 32 bit registers...  Not really something people do...

Comment: I'm moving pointers in and out of registers - I'm really only using eax, edi, and esi.  I'm using Microsoft's ML compiler, as the .asm file is part of a c++ project.

Comment: If you are just moving some pointers around, why use assembly in the first place?